# OpenVpn appliance: where to put cert files for HTTPS of builtin web server?

Tags: openvpn, webserver, certbot

I successfully run OpenVpn appliance. It a VM Ware , to be precise.

I finally run certbot and so I got two pem files .

I was hoping that certbot could install the certificate files automatically, but when entering the OpenVpn gui at 443 port, Chrome still warns about insecure state of the site.

Where and how must I copy these two files?

I followed this tutorial: https://loige.co/using-lets-encrypt-and-certbot-to-automate-the-creation-of-certificates-for-openvpn/

I done

```
sudo apt-get -y install software-properties-common  
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:certbot/certbot  
sudo apt-get -y update  
sudo apt-get -y install certbot 

sudo certbot certonly \  
  --standalone \ 
  --non-interactive \ 
  --agree-tos \ 
  --email YOUR_CERTIFICATE_EMAIL \ 
  --domains YOUR_DOMAIN \ 
  --pre-hook 'sudo service openvpnas stop' \ 
  --post-hook 'sudo service openvpnas start'

sudo ln -s -f \
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/YOUR_DOMAIN/cert.pem \
   /usr/local/openvpn_as/etc/web-ssl/server.crt  
sudo ln -s -f \
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/YOUR_DOMAIN/privkey.pem \
   /usr/local/openvpn_as/etc/web-ssl/server.key  

sudo service openvpnas start
```

> Obiously, I wrote my *real* domain and not the placeholder

But, while the certbot is succesfully run, and `.pem` files created, the `link` and the `restart` commands are not enough to make my https connections be secure.

I think the tutorial was old, but I do not know how to telle the webserver of openvpn to keep and use this files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full working solution

> IMPORTANT: do not link files as in my question !

**Install**

```
sudo apt-get -y install software-properties-common  
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:certbot/certbot  
sudo apt-get -y update  
sudo apt-get -y install certbot
```

**Create the certificate**

```
sudo certbot certonly --standalone --non-interactive --agree-tos \
     --email <youremail> --domains <thedomain> \
     --pre-hook 'sudo service openvpnas stop' \
     --post-hook 'sudo service openvpnas start'
```

> To renew, simply add `--force-renew`.

**Add certificates to webserver config using `sacli` tool**

```
./sacli --key "cs.priv_key" --value_file \
    "/etc/letsencrypt/live/<yourdomain>/privkey.pem" ConfigPut

./sacli --key "cs.cert" --value_file \
    "/etc/letsencrypt/live/<yourdomain>/cert.pem" ConfigPut

./sacli --key "cs.ca_bundle" --value_file \
    "/etc/letsencrypt/live/<yourdomain>/fullchain.pem" ConfigPut
```

**Restart the service**

```
./sacli start
```

To check, use, for example, the free online tool at https://www.digicert.com/help/

> Note: I am not related to digicert.